# Why Bockstein Spectral Sequence uses prime numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I am curious why the Bockstein spectral sequence uses a prime $p$ for the exact sequence of coefficients $$0\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$

Will the theory still work if $p$ is replaced by any other integer $a\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you include into "the theory". The above sequence works for all integers, but for some of the other results you'll need $p$ prime.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Could you give one example of the results where $p$ is needed to be prime? Thanks.

Comment: I am no expert for this "theory", but I suppose that almost everything fails which is related to the fact, that $\mathbb{Z}/a$ is only a field for $a=p$ prime. For example, the Bockstein homomorphism $\beta_p$ is one of the generators of the Steenrod algebra. If $p$ is not prime, then we do not have a finite field for the Steenrod algebra.

Comment: Note that any interger $r$ can be written uniqely as a product of primes $r=p_1^{r_1}\dots p_n^{r_n}$. Hence for each prime $p_i$ that appears you get a Bockstein spectral squence for the $p_i$-torsion in $H_(-;\mathbb{Z}_r)$. Furthermore note that $red_{p_i}\circ red_r=red_{p_i}$. Hence you may as well study the $p_i$-torsion to begin with.